# Limit of $1/e^x$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

I think that I have confused myself somehow with this limit. So I would be grateful if you could clarify this for me. The question was to compute 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^x}
$$
This is a very simple limit but I am not sure why I have confused myself. Here is my lecturer solution:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{x}=0
$$
and Here is my solution:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}&=0\\
\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-x}&=\infty
\end{align*}
$$
Since the two limits are not the same, then the limit of $1/e^x$ as $x\to\infty$ does not exist.

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I know that but I think you did not get the point of my question. I am saying that I think, the limit as $x\to\infty$ exits if and only if the limits as $x\to\pm\infty$ exists and are equal.

Comment: You are confusing $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)$, the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ from the left, with $\lim_{x\to -a}f(x)$, which is an entirely different thing.  It is true that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists if and only if the two one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ (the two one sided limits) exist and are equal. This has nothing to do with $\lim_{x\to -a}$ and $\lim_{x\to a}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: thank you. That answers my question perfectly. Now I see what was wrong with my logic.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's very well explained. Post it as an official answer so that user172675 can accept it.

Comment: @Duncan: The answer by Theo now incorporates similar content, and in any case now the OP knows the source of the confusion, so there is no need of another formal answer.

Comment: Yup - I posted my comment before Theo's answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is that $\infty$ is not treated as the other limits. From one point of view $\infty$ might only be considered a limit from the left. You are right in a sense that if we would compactify the real line (i.e. make $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ touch and change the real line to a circle), then the new funky function that would arise from $e^x$ would not have a limit on the single new point $\infty$. Indeed, because the left and right limits would be different.

However, this is not the case; for our normal 1-dimensional calculus we always only approach $\infty$ from the left...

Let me also add that the comments above are correct and perhaps to a better direction than my answer. You were confusing $\operatorname{lim}_{x\rightarrow a^{-}}$ with $\operatorname{lim}_{x\rightarrow -a}$. It just so happens that when $a=\infty$ this confusion isn't terribly wrong in the sense that one might see $\operatorname{lim}_{x\rightarrow -\infty^{-}}$ as the same thing as $\operatorname{lim}_{x\rightarrow \infty}$